# Trouble Writing multiThread Chat program

Tags: multithreading

im writing a multithread chat program where i hope to have a server connected to multiple clients, the clients can talk to each and send messages to each other. I want all messages from the clients to be visible to the server, moreover that the server can send messages to all visible clients. My program only connects the server to one client and they can send messages.

```
package chatserver2;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;
   // import all the class that you will need for functionailty

// extends jframe to develop gui's in java
public class Server2 {

    private static JTextField userInput; // 
    private static JTextArea theChatWindow; //
    private static ObjectOutputStream output; // stream data out
    private static ObjectInputStream input; // stream data in
    private static ServerSocket server;
    private static Socket connection; // socket means set up connetion between 2 computers
    private static JFrame frame;
    private static int n;

//Constructor
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Server2 obj = new Server2();
//        Socket sock=new Socket("localhost",6789);
        System.out.println("Hello 4");
        obj.RunServer();
        System.out.println("Hello 3");
        try {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Hello 2");

                Handler obj2 = new Handler();
                //Handler obj3=new Handler();
                obj2.start();
                System.out.println("Accepted connection from "
                        + connection.getInetAddress() + " at port "
                        + connection.getPort());

                n++;
                System.out.println("Count " + n);
            }
        } finally {
            connection.close();
        }

    }

    public Server2() {

        frame = new JFrame();
        userInput = new JTextField();
        userInput.setEditable(false); // set this false so you dont send messages when noone is available to chat
        // action event listener to check when the user hits enter for example
        userInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                sendMessage(event.getActionCommand()); // string entered in the textfield
                userInput.setText(""); // reset text area to blank again

            }
        }
        );
        // create the chat window
        frame.add(userInput, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        theChatWindow = new JTextArea();
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(theChatWindow));
        frame.setSize(300, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

// run the server after gui created
    public void RunServer() {

        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(6789); // 1st number is port number where the application is located on the server, 2nd number is the amount of people aloud to connect
            while (true) {

                try {
                    waitForConnection(); // wait for a connection between 2 computers 
                    setupStreams();  // set up a stream connection between 2 computers to communicate
                    whileChatting();  // send message to each other
                    // connect with someone and have a conversation
                } catch (EOFException eofException) {

                    showMessage("\n Server ended Connection");
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ioException) {

            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

//Wait for a connection then display connection information
    private void waitForConnection() {

        showMessage("waiting for someone to connect to chat room....\n");
        try {
            connection = server.accept();
        } catch (IOException ioexception) {

            ioexception.printStackTrace();
        }
        showMessage("Now connected to" + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
        showMessage(" at port " + connection.getPort());

    }
    // stream function to send and recive data

    private void setupStreams() throws IOException {

        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); // set up pathway to send data out
        output.flush(); // move data away from your machine
        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); // set up pathway to allow data in

        // String message = "WAIT";
        // sendMessage(message);
        //showMessage("\n Connection streams are now setup \n");
    }

// this code while run during chat conversions
    private void whileChatting() throws IOException {

        String message = "WAIT ";
        sendMessage(message);
        allowTyping(true); // allow user to type when connection
        do {
            // have conversion while the client does not type end
            try {

                message = (String) input.readObject(); // stores input object message in a string variable
                showMessage("\n " + message);
                System.out.println("Message from Client " + message);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException classnotfoundException) {

                showMessage("\n i dont not what the user has sent");
            }
        } while (!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));// if user types end program stops

    }

    private void closeChat() {

        showMessage("\n closing connections...\n");
        allowTyping(true);
        try {

            output.close(); // close output stream
            input.close(); // close input stream
            connection.close(); // close the main socket connection

        } catch (IOException ioexception) {

            ioexception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

// send message to the client
    private void sendMessage(String message) {

        try {

            output.writeObject(message);
            output.flush(); // send all data out
            showMessage("\nServer - " + message);
            System.out.println("Message to client " + message);

        } catch (IOException ioexception) {

            theChatWindow.append("\n ERROR: Message cant send");
        }

    }

// update the chat window (GUI)
    private void showMessage(final String text) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {

                        theChatWindow.append(text);

                    }
                }
        );

    }

// let the user type messages in their chat window
    private void allowTyping(final boolean trueOrFalse) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {

                        userInput.setEditable(trueOrFalse);

                    }
                }
        );

    }

    public static class Handler extends Thread {

        private Socket connection;

        //  static private ServerSocket server;
        public Handler() {
            //  this.socket = socket;
            String message = "WAIT";

        }

        //connection = server.accept();
        public void run() {

            System.out.println("Connect" + Server2.connection);
            while (true) {

                try {
                    waitForConnection();
                    setupStreams();
                    whileChatting();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Server2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }

        }

        private void waitForConnection() {
            System.out.println("Heelo");
            showMessage("waiting for someone to connect to chat room....\n");
            System.out.println("server" + server);
            try {
                connection = server.accept();
            } catch (IOException ioexception) {

                ioexception.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Connection" + connection);

            showMessage("Now connected to" + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
            showMessage("AT port" + connection.getPort());
        }

        private void setupStreams() throws IOException {

            output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); // set up pathway to send data out
            output.flush(); // move data away from your machine
            input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); // set up pathway to allow data in
            showMessage("\n Connection streams are now setup \n");

        }

// this code while run during chat conversions
        private void whileChatting() throws IOException {

            String message = " You are now connected ";
            sendMessage(message);
            allowTyping(true); // allow user to type when connection
            do {
                // have conversion while the client does not type end
                try {

                    message = (String) input.readObject(); // stores input object message in a string variable
                    showMessage("\n " + message);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException classnotfoundException) {

                    showMessage("\n i dont not what the user has sent");
                }
            } while (!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));// if user types end program stops

        }

        private void closeChat() {

            showMessage("\n closing connections...\n");
            allowTyping(true);
            try {

                output.close(); // close output stream
                input.close(); // close input stream
                connection.close(); // close the main socket connection

            } catch (IOException ioexception) {

                ioexception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

// send message to the client
        static private void sendMessage(String message) {

            try {

                output.writeObject(message);
                output.flush(); // send all data out
                showMessage("\nServer - " + message);

            } catch (IOException ioexception) {

                theChatWindow.append("\n ERROR: Message cant send");
            }

        }

// update the chat window (GUI)
        static private void showMessage(final String text) {

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                    new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {

                            theChatWindow.append(text);

                        }
                    }
            );

        }

// let the user type messages in their chat window
        private void allowTyping(final boolean trueOrFalse) {

            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                    new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {

                            userInput.setEditable(trueOrFalse);

                        }
                    }
            );

        }

    }

}
```

Here is the client :

```
package chatserver2;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
   // import all the class that you will need for functionailty

// extends jframe to develop gui's in java
public class Client2 extends JFrame {

    private JTextField userInput; // 
    private JTextArea theChatWindow; //
    private ObjectOutputStream output; // stream data out
    private ObjectInputStream input; // stream data in

    private Socket connection; // socket means set up connetion between 2 computers

//Constructor
    public Client2() {

        super("My Chat Service");
        userInput = new JTextField();
        userInput.setEditable(false); // set this false so you dont send messages when noone is available to chat
        // action event listener to check when the user hits enter for example
        userInput.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                sendMessage(event.getActionCommand()); // string entered in the textfield
                userInput.setText(""); // reset text area to blank again

            }
        }
        );
        // create the chat window
        add(userInput, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        theChatWindow = new JTextArea();
        add(new JScrollPane(theChatWindow));
        setSize(300, 150);
        setVisible(true);
    }

// run the server after gui created






    public void RunServer() {

        try {
            connection = new Socket("localhost", 6789);// 1st number is port number where the application is located on the server, 2nd number is the amount of people aloud to connect
            while (true) {

                try {
                    // wait for a connection between 2 computers 
                    setupStreams();  // set up a stream connection between 2 computers to communicate
                    whileChatting();  // send message to each other
                    // connect with someone and have a conversation
                } catch (EOFException eofException) {

                    showMessage("\n Server ended Connection");
                } finally {

                    closeChat();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ioException) {

            ioException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

//Wait for a connection then display connection information
    // stream function to send and recive data
    private void setupStreams() throws IOException {

        output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream()); // set up pathway to send data out
        output.flush(); // move data away from your machine
        input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); // set up pathway to allow data in
        showMessage("\n Connection streams are now setup \n");

    }

// this code while run during chat conversions
    private void whileChatting() throws IOException {

        String message = "";

        allowTyping(true); // allow user to type when connection
        do {
            // have conversion while the client does not type end
            try {

                message = (String) input.readObject(); // stores input object message in a string variable
                System.out.println("message " + message);
                if (message.equals("WAIT")) {
                    ServerSocket server2 = new ServerSocket(5000);
                    System.out.println("Hello");
                    message = "5000";
                    sendMessage(message);

                }
                System.out.println("From server " + message);

                showMessage("\n " + message);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException classnotfoundException) {

                showMessage("\n i dont not what the user has sent");
            }
        } while (!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));// if user types end program stops

    }

    private void closeChat() {

        showMessage("\n closing connections...\n");
        allowTyping(true);
        try {

            output.close(); // close output stream
            input.close(); // close input stream
            connection.close(); // close the main socket connection

        } catch (IOException ioexception) {

            ioexception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

// send message to the client
    private void sendMessage(String message) {

        try {

            output.writeObject(" - " + message);
            output.flush(); // send all data out
            showMessage("\nServer - " + message);

        } catch (IOException ioexception) {

            theChatWindow.append("\n ERROR: Message cant send");
        }

    }

// update the chat window (GUI)
    private void showMessage(final String text) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {

                        theChatWindow.append(text);

                    }
                }
        );

    }

// let the user type messages in their chat window
    private void allowTyping(final boolean trueOrFalse) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
                new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {

                        userInput.setEditable(trueOrFalse);

                    }
                }
        );

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client2 obj = new Client2();
        obj.RunServer();
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to state specifically what you are having issues with. Do you get compile issues, are you unable to connect to the server process?

Comment: This code run's. My problem is connecting to multiple Clients

Comment: I want the server to send message to two clients while the two clients connected to the server and send messages to each other. all messages that are sent are visible to the server